# Regular expression for checking a string, which must contain a space and be alpha numeric

Tags: javascript, regex

Can any one give the regular expression for checking a string

which must contain a space and be alpha numeric.

Comment: If there's a space, it's not alphanumeric.

Comment: one single space anywhere in the string and the rest should be alnum chars?

Comment: yes Adirau, , will you please give the regular expression for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript you can solve it like this:

```
if (/^[a-z\d]* [a-z\d]*$/i.test(input)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Fail
}
```

Notes:

- The `i` following the regex means
  ignore case, i.e. it matchez a-z as
  well as A-Z
- The regex says: in the beginning,
  find zero to many alphanums, then a
  space and finally zero to many
  alphanums before the string ends
- the string you test is `input`
- If you want to make sure that there's at least one alphanum before and after the space, then use `+` instead of `*`

Comment: That will also allow only 1 space with no leading or trailing letters or numbers.

Comment: @RobG Exactly! This is intentionally and according to the spec: "one single space anywhere in the string and the rest should be alnum chars? yes" (from second and third comment to the question itself)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want the space to be between two alpha numeric substrings.  I have also added `\s*` to allow for whitespace encasing the alpha-numerics (which judging by your comment is what you actually want)

```
^\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]+[ ][0-9a-zA-z]+\s*$
```

Comment: Note that the character range `A-z` is *not* equal to `A-Za-z` as `A-z` does also contain the characters `[\]^_\`` that are between `Z` (U+00A5) and `a` (U+0061).

Comment: it is almost ok,but this will fail  for the string 12 16  . So i need it should check , whether there is any character too.Thanks for the help

Comment: @user310850, It seems like you want to allow whitespace around your strings, so I updated the regex.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+ [A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

If the space can be at the end or the beginning, change the correspondent `+` to `*`.